# Delete document after download through visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a visualforce page with a button to download a document, this work fine, but after download the document I want to delete the file without to click in another button, this is the code I am using:

```
<apex:page standardController="npe03__Recurring_Donation__c" extensions="ReporteCompromisosExportacionController" action="{!getFile}" tabStyle="Reporte_Compromisos__tab">    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="download" action="{!downloadFile}"/>
        <apex:actionFunction name="deletef" action="{!deleteFile}" rerender="name"/>
        <apex:pageBlock id="page">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Descargar Archivo de Cobranza" collapsible="false">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:image url="{!$Resource.excelIcon}" width="30" height="30"/>
                    <apex:outputText id="name" value="Archivo {!fileName}"/>                    
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:CommandButton value="Descargar Archivo" action="{!downloadFile}" oncomplete="deletef();" rerender="name"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public void getFile(){
        String idDocument = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('doc');
        List<Document> docs = [SELECT Name FROM Document WHERE Id =: idDocument];
        if(docs.size()>0){
            fileName = docs.get(0).Name;
        }       
    }

    public String downloadFile(){
        String idDocument = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('doc');
        String URL = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + idDocument;
        return URL;     
    }

    public void deleteFile(){
        String idDocument = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('doc');
        Document d = new Document();
        d.Id = idDocument;
        delete d;
    }
}
```

The oncomple method doesn't work, can some one help me please?

Comment: What does the `{!downloadFile} do? It redirect to document url?

Comment: Please share your extension code.

Comment: Ashwani downloadFile return a String with the URL to the file, AdrianLarson, I edit the question with the extension code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not delete the document until and unless you make sure that document is downloaded successfully.

You current approach can delete the document even it is in middle of download. Because as soon as `String` (url) is returned, it will call the `oncomplete` and delete the document. This will halt the download immediately. *Assuming the case if `oncomplete` works*

Instead, you just make the `idDocument` to `null` so, if user click on the button it won't be able to get the file as `ID` is `null`.

Have some asynchronous process lets say scheduled `Batch` to delete the document after 5 minutes or the considerable time when you are sure that document would be downloaded upto that time.

**OnComplete** doesn't work because method `downloadFile` must return either `PageReference` type or `void`. `null` return would also acceptable.